# Which user is running the tomcat on Amazon EC2?

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a `Tomcat 7` server running on Amazon EC2 (OS - Ubuntu 12 LTS). How can I find out which user is running `Tomcat` on Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
ps auxwww | grep tomcat | grep -v grep
```

you will get output like this

```
    $ ps auxwww | grep tomcat | grep -v grep
root      1941  0.2  1.7 419224 35208 ?        Sl   Aug12   0:06 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

there you get the process owner name and process id..